# Kubernetes pod level configuration externalization in spring boot app

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I need some help from the community, I'm still new to K8 and Spring Boot.  Thanks all in advance.
what I need is  to have 4 K8 pods running in K8 environment and each pod have slightly different configuration from each other, for example, I have a property in one of my java class called regions, it extract it's value from Application.yml, like

**@Value("${regions}")

Private String regions;**

Now after deploy it to K8 env I want to have 4 pods(I can configure it in helm file) running and in each pod the **regions** field should have different value.
Is this something achievable ? Can anyone please give any advice ?

Comment: the fact that you are using `helm` simplifies the tasks _a lot_. You can define the regions you care in `values.yaml` and apply as needed and expose those as environment properties in the deployment file. Spring, in turn, has `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that will read env variables that helm will set. And do not use `@Value`, but go for `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run **4** different pods with different configurations, you have to deploy the **4** different deployments in **kubernetes**.

You can create the different `configmap` as per need storing the whole `Application.yaml` file or environment variables and inject it to **different** **deployments**.

how to store whole `application.yaml` inside `config map`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: yaml-region-first
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    data: test,
    region: first-region
```

the same way you can create the config map with the second deployment.

```
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: yaml-region-second
    data:
      application.yaml: |-
        data: test,
        region: second-region
```

you can inject this `configmap` to each deployment

example :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hello-app
  name: hello-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: hello-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/nginx/app.yaml
            name: yaml-file
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: yaml-region-second
          optional: false
        name: yaml-file
```

accordingly, you can also create the helm chart.

If you just to pass the single environment instead of storing the whole file inside the `configmap` you can directly add value to the deployment.

Example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: print-greeting
spec:
  containers:
  - name: env-print-demo
    image: bash
    env:
    - name: REGION
      value: "one"
    - name: HONORIFIC
      value: "The Most Honorable"
    - name: NAME
      value: "Kubernetes"
    command: ["echo"]
    args: ["$(GREETING) $(HONORIFIC) $(NAME)"]
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

for each deployment, your environment will be different and in helm, you can `dynamically` also `update` or `overwrite` it using CLI command.

Comment: Thank you Harsh, I will try this, I'll post the outcome here.

Comment: The solution worked, handed over to deployment team for multiple K8 deployment. thanks again.

Comment: glad to hear that, you can also upvote answer if helpful:)...!

Comment: I wanted to but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: have you read that the OP is using helm? this is rather weird way to provide a solution. and you do _not_ need to store the spring application file in a config map, there is an environment post processor.